# What happens when consumer maxAttempts is reached?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

With the following configuration and scenario, what happens when maxAttempts is reached?

Spring Cloud Stream with Kafka binding and the following properties:

- spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.maxAttempts=3
- spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOffset=true
- spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.autoCommitOnError=false
- spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings.input.consumer.enableDlq=false

Here's the scenario:

- Consumer via @StreamListener annotation receives the message payload
- Prior to returning from the annotated method, the consumer tries to persist the message in a database
- The database is down and a runtime exception is thrown from the @StreamListener annotated method

The behavior i'm seeing is the consumer retries the message until the maxAttempts limit is reached.  Then nothing happens until i restart the service.  Upon restart the message is re-consumed.

What happens if the db becomes available again after maxAttempts is reached?  Is my only option to restart the service?  Is there a way to set maxAttempts to infinity?

I suspect I'm not fully understanding the behavior

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed the expected behavior, since you set to not autocommit erroneous messages. What happens is that this gives a chance for the client to replay from the last committed offset.

The problem in setting maxAttempts to infinity is when an non recoverable error happens, you would then have your listener trying to consume the message over and over again.

A better approach may be setting a dlq for those messages and then using a PollableChannel to poll messages periodically and attempt to reprocess them, this would give some time for your external resource to recover.